# Are there any open source OpenSocial containers?

Tags: liferay, opensocial

Is there an [OpenSocial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial) container based on open source or any similar social collaboration software that is open source?

I have already looked on [Liferay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay), but it seems a bit complex, and I don't really enjoy the technology stack.

Answer (score 3):

opensocial.org provides a list of Open Source containers: http://docs.opensocial.org/display/OSD/List+of+OpenSocial+Containers

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of http://incubator.apache.org/shindig/ (but never tested it, beware ...)

Comment: +1: shindig is very comprehensive but almost totally undocumented (their developers admit as much), which is a big downer...